# 3-Tier architecture-layering and the term-mishmash

Tags: architecture, 3-tier

I am confused about the different possibilities to express a 3-Tier architecture.

```
Data-Access-Layer
Business-Layer
Presentation Layer (User Interface)
```

or

```
Database (aka Backend)
Business-Layer
Presentation Layer (User Interface)
```

Why can you skip the database in the 1st approach? Both use a database!
Does the database belong to the layering or not?!

What is wrong and what is right?

Can someone of you clarify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Data-Access-Layer
Business-Layer
Presentation Layer (User Interface)
```

Data-Access-Layer is not necessarily a database.  It could be an XML file.  It could be an RSS feed.  It could be an external application.  It could be anything you like that gets data into your application.

So it's really:

```
[Data-Source]
Data-Access-Layer
Business-Layer
Presentation Layer (User Interface)
```

where `[Data-Source]` is database, XML, RSS, whatever... I prefer to think of the data-source itself as a driver, not a layer.

The flexibility of this approach allows you to swap out your data source without touching the rest of the application.  So if you began by using XML files as your back-end data, and then you want to change it to a database instead, you only touch the DAL layer - the rest of the application doesn't care as long as it still gets the data in the same format.

Comment: the term data-source is interessting. For me this term says that the database has no logic. Is this assumption right?
What is when my database contains the whole Business logic? Do I still have a Business-Layer?

Comment: You'll find there are plenty of discussions about whether it's "correct" to put business logic into a database.  What if you decide to change database servers from MS SQL to MySQL?  Suddenly you have to rewrite your business logic.  What if you remove the database altogether, and use XML instead? Your logic is gone. Plus if you have business logic that makes no sense to be in the database, you're maintaining business logic in two places - a bad idea. Other times the business logic can only function in the context of the database.  You have to tailor the abstraction to your particular situation

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic offers articles from both points of view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that your dal may not use a db it could use an xml file?

The first approach is using a more abstract concept which is what the 3 tier layer is.

The stuff that goes in each layer depends on the implementation the the tiers. Yuo may find that you mix your layers between GUI/DB/BizLogic 'programs' but in the abstract you still mantain those layers.

> Data-Access-Layer
>   Business-Layer
>   Presentation Layer (User Interface)

Considering  the above you may wirte code that connects to your db. Is that the DAL or the logic?

I'd consider that the DAL as you are writing to code to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

**Presentation tier**
    This is the topmost level of the application. The presentation tier displays information related to such services as browsing merchandise, purchasing, and shopping cart contents. It communicates with other tiers by outputting results to the browser/client tier and all other tiers in the network.

**Application tier** (Business Logic/Logic Tier/Data Access Tier/Middle Tier)
    The logic tier is pulled out from the presentation tier and, as its own layer, it controls an application’s functionality by performing detailed processing.

**Data tier**
    This tier consists of Database Servers. Here information is stored and retrieved. This tier keeps data neutral and independent from application servers or business logic. Giving data its own tier also improves scalability and performance. 

See following for more details:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Patterns and Practices group has an excellent [architecture guide](http://apparchguide.codeplex.com/wikipage) that goes through all the variations on this issue. It's slightly focused towards .NET, but is very applicable to any environment. Highly recommended.